# Convert boolean to int in Java

Tags: java, casting, boolean, int

What is the most accepted way to convert a `boolean` to an `int` in Java?

Comment: What integers would you think corresponded to `true` and `false` respectively?

Comment: Some languages have implicit conversion from int to boolean. Java doesn't. However, the official implementation has SQL packages, and I believe these convert "false" to 0.

Comment: Generally, a boolean should be left as a boolean.  This is the accepted practice in Java.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Not if you want to interoperate with other systems that don't have boolean as a non-numeric data type.

Comment: @hgpc, in which can you know which values you need true and false to represent. These are usually byte values (though most of the examples here are int values) but can be '0' or '1' (48 and 49) or 'T' and 'F', 'Y' or 'N' and their ascii values.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey The question is not really about the value mapping. It's about how to do the conversion in the most clear, accepted way.

Comment: @hgpc, you cannot code a mapping, if you don't know what to map to.

Comment: Technically, the Java compiler already defines a mapping. True and False are compiled to 1 and 0 respectively.

Comment: I have answered on similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806021/checking-the-boolean-result-of-an-int-type/39878780#39878780)

Comment: What's the use case for that question?

Comment: Why can't (int)[boolean_variable] be used my compiler shows an error

Answer (score 708, accepted):

```
int myInt = myBoolean ? 1 : 0;
```

^^

PS : true = 1 and false = 0

Comment: In the case where myBoolean stands for a boolean expression, using parenthesis is more readable.

Comment: Yes, as in `(foo && (!bar || baz)) ? 1 : 0`.  Obviously, if it's just an identifier, the parens aren't necessary or desirable.

Comment: nice trick with boolean! I was looking might some casting exist like (int) true = 1, but noting exist like this :P

Comment: for beginners like me, `(boolean expression) ? 1 : 0;` would be more understandable. I think `my` prefix made it look like a variable.

Comment: @Blrfl in your example parentheses are a *must*, not a matter of readability.  `foo && (!bar || baz) ? 1 : 0` would be a syntax error. (I know it's been 6 years)

Comment: @KonradMorawski in what way does `foo && (!bar || baz) ? 1 : 0` cause a syntax error? `?:` has lower precedence than both `&&` and `||`.

Comment: now with even **more truth** `int myInt = myBoolean ? ~0 : 0`

Comment: I put an edit that added examples of how to use it in the middle of a numerical expression.

Comment: The only operator precedence that is fine not to know right off your hand is `<<`, `&`, and `==` because C made it weird. If the boolean expression on `?:` is longer, I put `?` on a new line and `:` on the next new line. Operator precedence exists for a reason and is logical for the most part. I’d say superfluous parentheses obfuscate.

Answer (score 164):

```
int val = b? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 81):

Using the ternary operator is the most simple, most efficient, and most readable way to do what you want. I encourage you to use this solution.

However, I can't resist to propose an alternative, contrived, inefficient, unreadable solution.

```
int boolToInt(Boolean b) {
    return b.compareTo(false);
}
```

Hey, people like to vote for such cool answers !

**Edit**

By the way, I often saw conversions from a boolean to an int for the sole purpose of doing a comparison of the two values (generally, in implementations of `compareTo` method). `Boolean#compareTo` is the way to go in those specific cases.

**Edit 2**

Java 7 introduced a new utility function that works with primitive types directly, `Boolean#compare` (Thanks *shmosel*)

```
int boolToInt(boolean b) {
    return Boolean.compare(b, false);
}
```

Comment: Will be inlined by modern JIT's, so not necessarily inefficient.  Also it documents why the b.compareTo is being used so it is readable.

Comment: It can be slow because we need to box the primitive value in an object. The ternary operator method works directly with primitive values without conversion, so I think it's more efficient.

Comment: 1. You can use `Boolean.compare()` and avoid the autoboxing.
2. The documentation for `Boolean.compareTo()` does not say it will return 1, only "a positive value if this object represents true and the argument represents false".

Comment: I just did a test converting 1,000,000 random Boolean values and this method was consistently faster than that based on the ternary operator. It shaved off about 10ms.

Comment: @AlexT. if you do microbenchmarks you should use a framework to ensure that you measure correctly.  See http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen What did your test conclude? I used a visitor pattern to emulate an if statement, and provided the objects involved with the visitor pattern were pre allocated, the ternary operator was consistently slower. I assume this had to do with branch prediction.

Comment: I really needed `Boolean#compare` ;)

Comment: @AlexT. I did not conclude anything.  Perhaps you could make your test available so we can reproduce it?

Answer (score 53):

```
boolean b = ....; 
int i = -("false".indexOf("" + b));
```

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yeah. Using one of the other, more efficient, methods posted that doesn't require that overhead. Unless you can explain how creating string objects to simply check the value of a boolean is in any way efficient.

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy you are micro-optimizing prematurely.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Micro-optimization has nothing to do with it, since it's all a matter of context. If I'm calling a method 1000000+ times which uses this block, then I'm potentially creating 1000000+ extra objects that need to be GC'd. I'm not sure how demanding things are at your job, but my boss would pull me aside and give me a wtf lecture if I tried using something like this.

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy if you call a slow method a gazillion times your boss should lecture you on memoization instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have no control over how my methods are used or how often they are called, which is entirely the point. You're sacrificing both performance and readability for absolutely no tangible benefit.

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy So if I used `Boolean.toString(b)` instead of `"" + b` in order to avoid the string concatenation that would be ok with you?

Comment: Its definitely creative but I cannot think of a single advantage to using this method. It's more verbose, and (I'm guessing) less efficient, but it sure is an interesting method.

Comment: @kennytm: Brilliant hack... but tiny nit pick: If `b` is primitive `boolean`, I think you need to use: `5 - Boolean.toString(b).length`

Comment: @kevinarpe, then `5 - Boolean.toString(b).length()`

Comment: I'm going to upvote if this is sarcasm, in which case it's hilarious. I just can't figure if it is

Comment: Even though this code might be valid and technically correct, aside from being inefficient compared to other suggestions, it is hard to read and understand. I would not recommend using this.

Answer (score 30):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils;
boolean x = true;   
int y= BooleanUtils.toInteger(x);
```

Comment: FWIW, `BooleanUtils.toInteger` is implemented as just `return bool ? 1 : 0;`.

Comment: Apache Commons can be useful, but this is just ridiculous.

Comment: @EricDuminil This can slightly increase readability in case of nested ( ? : ) or long one-liners.

Comment: @EricDuminil IMO `xyz.stream().map(BooleanUtils::toInteger)` is much more readable than `xyz.stream().map(x -> x ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: @bb1950328: Yes, it's more readable, but it doesn't have anything to do with Apache Commons, though. You could simply use the method defined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3794521/6419007 instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this is common among unexperienced devs to include an entire library  with hundreds of classes and maybe even transitive dependencies just to use a few cheap utility functions. Ridiculous indeed.

Answer (score 28):

```
public int boolToInt(boolean b) {
    return b ? 1 : 0;
}
```

simple

Answer (score 19):

If you use [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) (which I think a lot of projects use it), you can just use it like this:

```
int myInt = BooleanUtils.toInteger(boolean_expression);
```

`toInteger` method returns 1 if `boolean_expression` is true, 0 otherwise

Comment: FWIW, `BooleanUtils.toInteger` is implemented as just `return bool ? 1 : 0;`.

Answer (score 16):

That depends on the situation. Often the most simple approach is the best because it is easy to understand:

```
if (something) {
    otherThing = 1;
} else {
    otherThing = 0;
}
```

or

```
int otherThing = something ? 1 : 0;
```

But sometimes it useful to use an Enum instead of a boolean flag. Let imagine there are synchronous and asynchronous processes:

```
Process process = Process.SYNCHRONOUS;
System.out.println(process.getCode());
```

In Java, enum can have additional attributes and methods:

```
public enum Process {

    SYNCHRONOUS (0),
    ASYNCHRONOUS (1);

    private int code;
    private Process (int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

Comment: An additional reason for using an if instead of `?:` is that you can put breakpoints inside the if blocks.

Comment: For the `enum`, why another member? Wouldn’t `ordinal()` be exactly right?

Answer (score 8):

If `true -> 1` and `false -> 0` mapping is what you want, you can do:

```
boolean b = true;
int i = b ? 1 : 0; // assigns 1 to i.
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to obfuscate, use this:

```
System.out.println( 1 & Boolean.hashCode( true ) >> 1 );  // 1
System.out.println( 1 & Boolean.hashCode( false ) >> 1 ); // 0
```

Answer (score 6):

Lets play trick with `Boolean.compare(boolean, boolean)`. Default behavior of function: if both values are equal than it returns `0` otherwise `-1`.

```
public int valueOf(Boolean flag) {
   return Boolean.compare(flag, Boolean.TRUE) + 1;
}
```

*Explanation*: As we know default return of Boolean.compare is -1 in case of mis-match so +1 make return value to **0** for `False` and **1** for `True`

Comment: `Boolean.compare(myBoolean, false)` would fit better accorning to the quoted description

Comment: @Vadzim Yes indeed will generate 1 and 0 by comparing with false and in current scenario it will generate 0 and -1. Both solutions are fine and +1 for your comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int convBool(boolean b)
{
int convBool = 0;
if(b) convBool = 1;
return convBool;
}
```

Then use :

```
convBool(aBool);
```