# Render a boolean as 0 or 1 in Play template

Tags: java, playframework

This is a simple question. What is the best way to render a boolean value of an object as '0' or '1' in a template in the Play Framework.

I am creating an XML structure, and the receiving side expect 1 or 0 and not the string 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793650/convert-boolean-to-int-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly trivial.

```
${myBoolVal ? 1:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Java object extensions:

```
${b.yesno("1", "0")}
```