# Casting Boolean To Int

Tags: java

I am going through a tutorial where so far it gives you the code below:

```
boolean p, q;

    System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");
    p = true; q = true;

    System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
    System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

    p = true; q = false;
    System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
    System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

    p = false; q = true;
    System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
    System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

    p = false; q = false;
    System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
    System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));
```

The task is to modify the program so that it uses `1's` and `0's` instead of `true` and `false`.

Im not sure if this is ment to be done by Casting Incompatible Types but I think that is the way to go as that is the section before it.

Can anyone give some advice and explanation as to why it works?

Comment: [This has been answered here already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793650/convert-boolean-to-int-in-java)

Comment: Think about renaming the question accordingly, because the title does not fit neither question nor answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not what the tutorial asks you to do. I think they want you to literally *replace* `boolean` with `int`, `true` with `1`, and `false` with `0`, like this:

```
int p, q;
System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");
p = 1; q = 1;
System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (1-p)); // EDIT: was !p
```

This will lead you to understanding of bitwise operations on integers `0` and `1`.

Comment: When I try this I get an error for `(!p)` saying `The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) int` the book does state that this may be a bit more complicated than first thought.

Comment: @Matt There is no unary equivalent to the `boolean` `!` (`~` flips all bits, not just the last one). the simplest way to achieve the result you are looking for is with `(1-p)`

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution
//Logic table using 1 and 0

class LogicOpTable {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

   int p, q;

   System.out.println("P\tQ\t"+
             "AND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");
   for (p = 1; p >= 0; p--) {
    for (q = 1; q >= 0; q--) {

   System.out.println(p + "\t" + q + "\t" +
             (p & q) + "\t" + (p | q) + 
                     "\t" + (p ^ q) + "\t" + (1 - p));
     }
  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a boolean to an int. These are completely different types.

But you can write a utility method `booleanToInt(boolean b)` which transforms a boolean into an int.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the ternary operator:

```
int logicalInt = boolVal? 1 : 0;
```

where "boolVal" is your boolean variable.

Comment: This hasn't been coverd in the book yet so I don't think this is the way to go :S

Answer (score 1):

You can use integers together with bitwise operators:

```java
int p, q;

System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");
p = 1;
q = 1;

System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
System.out.print((p & q) + "\t" + (p | q) + "\t");
System.out.println((p ^ q) + "\t" + (1-p));

p = 1;
q = 0;
System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
System.out.print((p & q) + "\t" + (p | q) + "\t");
System.out.println((p ^ q) + "\t" + (1-p));

p = 0;
q = 1;
System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
System.out.print((p & q) + "\t" + (p | q) + "\t");
System.out.println((p ^ q) + "\t" + (1-p));

p = 0;
q = 0;
System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
System.out.print((p & q) + "\t" + (p | q) + "\t");
System.out.println((p ^ q) + "\t" + (1-p));
```

Returns:

```
P   Q   AND OR  XOR NOT
1   1   1   1   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0
0   1   0   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast directly from a boolean to an int in Java. I would add a method along the lines of

```
public int getBoolValue(boolean b) {
 return b ? 1 : 0
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast int to boolean in java. Think of using

```java
boolean x = p & q;
boolean y = p | q;

(x ? 1 : 0)
```

For example

```java
System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
```

May become:

```java
System.out.print(x + "\t" + y + "\t");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to declare your variables as `int`s and assign `0` and `1` to `p` and `q`, and make sure you're using [java's bitwise operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) in all cases (at first glance it looks like you are).  [More info on bitwise operation from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Comment: When I try this I get an error for `(!p)` saying `The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) int` the book does state that this may be a bit more complicated than first thought.

Comment: As other people have said, you need to do 1-p instead of !p.