# Checking the "boolean" result of an "int" type

Tags: java, boolean, int, logical-operators

I'm learning Java, coming from C and I found an interesting difference between languages with the `boolean` type. In C there is no `bool`/`ean` so we need to use numeric types to represent boolean logic (`0 == false`).

I guess in Java that doesn't work:

```
int i = 1;
if (i)
    System.out.println("i is true");
```

Nor does changing the conditional via a typecast:

```
if ((boolean)i)
```

So besides doing something like:

```
if ( i != 0 )
```

Is there any other way to do a C-ish logic check on an `int` type? Just wondering if there were any Java tricks that allow boolean logic on non-boolean types like this.

---

**EDIT:** 

The example above was very simplistic and yields itself to a narrow scope of thinking. When I asked the question originally I was thinking about non-boolean returns from function calls as well. For example the Linux `fork()` call. It doesn't return an `int` per se, but I could use the numeric return value for a conditional nicely as in:

```
if( fork() ) {
    // do child code
```

This allows me to process the code in the conditional for the child, while not doing so for the parent (or in case of negative return result for an error).

So I don't know enough Java to give a good "Java" example at the moment, but that was my original intent.

Comment: No. (comment is NOT too short)

Comment: I don't think there is. What does the cast do?

Comment: The language spec explicitly states that there are no shortcuts and you must use comparison expressions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert boolean to int in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793650/convert-boolean-to-int-in-java)

Comment: @JanDvorak - The cast does the same thing as without it. Just errors out

Comment: @sampson-chen - that's boolean to an int, mine is int to a boolean... or are you considering that question the same?

Comment: @Doorknob - concise answer. thanks. ;)

Comment: with numbers, use `switch`.

Comment: @Mike No, this question is *not* a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @Mike oops, apologies; that's my mistake there.

Comment: Sigh, and the reviewer bots hit again... this is *not* a duplicate..

Comment: `In C there is no bool` - Er, [yes there is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608318/is-bool-a-native-c-type).

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - "The standard types in C, that is without including <bool.h>, do not include a `bool` type." - Is that better?

Comment: boolean b = i != 0;  if(b)//and so on....

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In Java,

```
if ( i != 0 )
```

is the idiomatic way to check whether the integer `i` differs from `zero`.

If `i` is used as a flag, it should be of type `boolean` and not of type `int`.

Comment: Got it, I guess I'll have to get used to having to write all those extra (`!=`) characters... thanks!

Comment: I think the *real* idiom is to use booleans. The above is a code smell, IMHO

Comment: Use booleans when you're only doing logic; do `!= 0` when there's an actual meaningful number.

Comment: How would one go about `(n & 1)` to check whether even or odd? stick a `==` or `!=` 0 at the end?

Answer (score 6):

Why not use the `boolean` type ? That will work as you expect without the potentially problematic integer/boolean conflation.

```
private boolean isValid;
...
if (!isValid) {
   ...
}
```

Note that this is the idiomatic Java approach. 3rd party libs use this, and consumers of your API will use and expect it too. I would expect libs that you use to give you `booleans`, and as such it's just you treating `ints` as `booleans`.

Comment: I can in this simple example. In more complex code I *know* I'm going to instinctually want to use int as boolean because I have for so many years... Just wondering if there was anything syntactically I could do in Java to allow it or if I would just have to get used to this.

Comment: I would try to address your instinctive urge! An integer is distinct from a boolean, and if you use an integer, one day you're going to put an unexpected value into it.

Comment: `if you use an integer, one day you're going to put an unexpected value into it` totally correct. and +1 just for this. However what I was thinking about was more the return from function calls. I don't have a good "java" example at the moment, but I was thinking about the Linux `fork()`, if I don't care about the value of the result I can say `if(fork())` to cover both the case of a failed fork and the parent and the code internal to the conditional is just the child's. I like being able to do that, even if it is a little less readable.

Comment: @Mike: Java is NOT C. Methods should return a value on success and *throw an exception* on failure. *Please* do not use `int` as a return type, unless you are planning to return an actual number...

Comment: @thkala is correct, in a Java environment other developers will expect an exception in case of a failure, not a "magic number" return value; up the call stack the exception can be caught, instead of checking for the specific magic number. Some conventions just don't transfer between languages, due to the spec of the language (integer having no implicit boolean representation) or additional features in the language (checked exceptions).

Answer (score 6):

Try [BooleanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#toBooleanObject(int)) from Apache [common-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

```
  BooleanUtils.toBoolean(0) = Boolean.FALSE
  BooleanUtils.toBoolean(1) = Boolean.TRUE
  BooleanUtils.toBoolean(2) = Boolean.TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

FROM [**JLS**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf):

> **The boolean type has two values, represented by the boolean literals
>   true and false, formed from ASCII letters.**

Thus no is the answer. the only was is

```
if ( i != 0 )
```

Comment: Nice link... Oracle is the keeper of the "official" Java documentation?

Comment: @Mike - yes. Sun was bought out by Oracle

Answer (score 2):

In java the condition has to be of type boolean else it can't be an expression, that is why

```
if( i )
```

is not allowed.

It has to be either true or false.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to use **int** instead of boolean, just
use a method to convert

```
class BooleanHelper
{
   public static boolean toBoolean (int pVal) {
      return pVal != 0;
   }
 ...
}

// apply

if (BooleanHelper.toBoolean(i)) { // BooleanHelper could be avoided using static imports...
```

However, just use

```
if (i != 0) {
```

is still shorter and clearer.

Comment: `is still shorter and clearer.` true, but I do like the concept of the "helper" function, +1 for it. Thanks.

Comment: Oh dear god do NOT go down this route!  [Madness awaits!](http://us.thedailywtf.com/Articles/Comparejava.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that. 
    Boolean i = true; 
    if (i)
        System.out.println("i is true");

Just initialize it as a boolean value rather than an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own enum if you would like to preserve semantics. Actually, you only need a single value enum, then you can directly compare its ordinal position.

```
enum bool{FALSE};

if(i != bool.FALSE.ordinal()){
   //true case logic
   }
else{ //false case logic
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably something like this:

`int i == 0 ? false : true;`

or the other way round:

`int i == 1 ? true : false`

...