# How to use this boolean in an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

```
private String getWhoozitYs(){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    boolean stop = generator.nextBoolean();
    if(stop = true)
    {
        sb.append("y");
        getWhoozitYs();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This is a chunk of code for a project I'm doing in a programming course. The problem I'm having is that after declaring the boolean stop and trying to assign a randomly generated boolean value to it, I can't use it in the if statement to determine if I should append more y's to the StringBuffer or not. I do have the Random generator inside a constructor, so that part isn't a problem. I assumed that since I declared the boolean outside the if statement I would be able to use it inside, but that doesn't seem to be the case. The real question is how can I use a randomly determined boolean in an if statement.

Comment: Hey i think you may figure this one out, it's a nice puzzle.. look up casting. esp. 0 and 1

Comment: Also, you can simply say `if(stop)` See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793650/convert-boolean-to-int-in-java

Answer (score 27):

`if(stop = true)` should be `if(stop == true)`, or simply (better!) `if(stop)`.

This is actually a good opportunity to see a reason to why always use `if(something)` if you want to see if it's `true` instead of writing `if(something == true)` (bad style!).

By doing `stop = true` then you are assigning `true` to `stop` and not comparing.

**So why the code below the `if` statement executed?**

See the [JLS - 15.26. Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26):

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of
>   the variable after the assignment has occurred. The result of an
>   assignment expression is not itself a variable.

So because you wrote `stop = true`, then you're satisfying the `if` condition.

Comment: Actually, it should just be `if (stop)`.  That's not even open to misinterpretation due to typos.  :P

Comment: the if is still comparing, it's just since stop gets set to true, it will always evaluate to true. sorry this is a nitpick but it seems like something worth explaining (since the OP is a beginner).

Comment: One doubt...    
`if(stop)` and `if(stop == true)` does second one need extra cpu cycles for execution. Programatically both interprete same, then why is it bad to use?

Comment: @unknown No complexity difference between the two. It's just like asking "Is it true that the variable is true" instead of "Is the variable true".

Comment: @MarounMaroun yes but at cpu instruction level I doubt that is the case. Because "is it true that the variable is true" has 2 conditions I think. Do you have any document or something for it?

Comment: And `if(stop)` can also be written as `if(((stop==true)==true)==true)` ?
I mean won't it affect? I'm not asking for code complexity, but for cpu cyle execution level. Just for why is it bad style?

Comment: @unknown I think that most compilers will optimize this.

Comment: for me `if(stop)` doesnt seem to work. However, if I do `if(stop == true)`, it works. Any thoughts?

Comment: @obaidmaroof no way.. please check again.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is

if `(stop = true)` is an assignment not a comparison.

Try `if (stop == true)`

Also take a look at the [Top Ten Errors Java Programmers Make](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the entire approach would be cleaner if you only had to use one instance of StringBuffer, instead of creating one in every recursive call... I would go for:

```
private String getWhoozitYs(){
     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
     while (generator.nextBoolean()) {
         sb.append("y");
     }

     return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(stop == true)
```

or

```
if(stop)
```

= is for assignment.

== is for checking condition.

```
if(stop = true)
```

It will assign true to stop and evaluates if(true). So it will always execute the code inside if because stop will always being assigned with true.

Answer (score 1):

Since `stop` is boolean you can change that part to:

```
//...
if(stop) // Or to: if (stop == true)
{
   sb.append("y");
   getWhoozitYs();
}
return sb.toString();
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
private String getWhoozitYs(){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    boolean stop = generator.nextBoolean();
    if(stop)
    {
        sb.append("y");
        getWhoozitYs();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

= is for assignment

write

```
if(stop){
   //your code
}
```

or

```
if(stop == true){
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

additionally you can just write

```
if(stop)
{
        sb.append("y");
        getWhoozitYs();
}
```