# modifying a logical operator truth table

Tags: java, truthtable

Everyone I was wondering if there's a simple way of converting the true and false values of this Java program, into 1's and 0's without doing too much manual labour?. I figured adding the data type "byte" and having two separate variable values of 1 and 0 and manually inputting them into the code would do but, is there a simpler way?

```
public class LogicalOpTable1 {

public static void main(String args[]) {

        boolean p, q;


        System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

        p = true; q = true;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q +"\t");
        System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

        p = true; q = false;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
        System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

        p = false; q = true;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
        System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));

        p = false; q = false;
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
        System.out.print((p&q) + "\t" + (p|q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p^q) + "\t" + (!p));
    }

}
```

Comment: In the simplest case you can use `p?1:0`, i.e. the ternary operator. You could go further and add a utility method that wraps  the operator.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You should write that as an answer.

Comment: This is from "a Java beginner's guide 5th edition", I just copied the code. Next time I have a question I'll try to simplify the code. All the replies are really informational, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Same code repeatedly used. Create a simple method by passing the boolean values as arguments.

[Method creation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm)

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.display(true, true);
        sample.display(true, false);
        sample.display(false, true);
        sample.display(false, false);

    }

    private void display(boolean p, boolean q)
    {
        System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
        System.out.print((p & q) + "\t" + (p | q) + "\t");
        System.out.println((p ^ q) + "\t" + (!p));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have much code duplication. **Never** copy paste, **Always** create methods. This will make your code readable and maintainable. Even in a simple exercise like this it is always good practice.

The easiest way to print `1` or `0` is to use the ternary operator, `boolean ? 1 : 0` will do the trick in very few characters.

Now, splitting your code into methods and applying the ternary operator we have:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");
    System.out.println(row(true, true));
    System.out.println(row(true, false));
    System.out.println(row(false, true));
    System.out.println(row(false, false));
}

private static String row(final boolean p, final boolean q) {
    return tabDelimited(p, q) + tabDelimited(p & q, p | q) + tabDelimited(p ^ q, !p);
}

private static String tabDelimited(final boolean a, final boolean b) {
    return (a ? 1 : 0) + "\t" + (b ? 1 : 0) + "\t";
}
```

A little bit better you'll agree?

Output:

```
P   Q   AND OR  XOR NOT
1   1   1   1   0   0   
1   0   0   1   1   0   
0   1   0   1   1   1   
0   0   0   0   0   1
```

You can then make the whole lot a little less hard-coded by making the `tabDelimited` method print any number of `boolean`s:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");
    System.out.println(row(true, true));
    System.out.println(row(true, false));
    System.out.println(row(false, true));
    System.out.println(row(false, false));
}

private static String row(final boolean p, final boolean q) {
    return tabDelimited(p, q, p & q, p | q, p ^ q, !p);
}

private static String tabDelimited(final boolean... toPrint) {
    if (toPrint.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(toPrint[0] ? 1 : 0);
    for (int i = 1; i < toPrint.length; ++i) {
        sb.append("\t").append(toPrint[i] ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java `boolean` is not convertible to `int` (1 or 0). Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793650/convert-boolean-to-int-in-java)

Alternatively you may use BooleanUtils from Apache [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/BooleanUtils.html#toInteger%28boolean%29)

Comment: You mean "Boolean does not have convertion methods". Of course you can "b?1:0". Introducing a dependency for this seems overkill to me.

Comment: I meant not convertible without an if statement. That dependency is for simplicity. You may create your own utility method :)

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be opinion based. If you care mostly on form of presentation then IMHO simplest would be your way mentioned in question -> changing `p` and `q` to integers. You would only have to change way of calculating NOT from `!p` to something like `1-p` or `1^p` because there is no single byte NOT operator.

Your code can look like

```
private static void printRow(int p, int q) {
    System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t");
    System.out.print((p & q) + "\t" + (p | q) + "\t");
    System.out.println((p ^ q) + "\t" + (1 - p));
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");

    printRow(1, 1);
    printRow(1, 0);
    printRow(0, 1);
    printRow(0, 0);
}
```

output:

```
P   Q   AND OR  XOR NOT
1   1   1   1   0   0
1   0   0   1   1   0
0   1   0   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Chapter2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("P\tQ\tAND\tOR\tXOR\tNOT");
        Compare(true ,true);
        Compare(true ,false);
        Compare(false ,true);
        Compare(false ,false);
    }
    static void Compare(boolean p, boolean q) {
        System.out.println((p?0:1) + "\t" + (q?0:1) +"\t"+((p&q)?0:1) + "\t" + 
            ((p|q)?0:1) + "\t" +((p^q)?0:1) + "\t" + ((!p)?0:1));
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a way to do this, since in that part of the book methods, :?, etc, and even if else aren't covered yet :

```
System.out.print(p + "\t" + q + "\t" + (p * q) + "\t");
if(p != q) System.out.println((p + q) + "\t" + (p + q) + "\t" + q);
if((p == q) & (p == 1)) System.out.println(p + "\t0\t0");
if((p == q) & (p == 0)) System.out.println(p + "\t0\t1");
```