# Can I convert boolean into another data type in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have the following code:

```
public class MyFirstJavaProgram {
        public static void main(String []args) { 
          boolean b = true; 
          int x = b; 
          System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

As the title say, can I convert boolean type into another data type (in the above example, `char`), using Java?

Comment: No...Use conditional statement if true set int to 1 else 0.

Comment: Java is a strong typed language, so the answer to this is definately NO

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert boolean to int in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793650/convert-boolean-to-int-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO
You use ternary operation

```
          int X = value ? 1: 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

No you cannot.

If you are looking for a one-line solution to set your `int`, you can use a ternary operation, as such:

```
int x = b ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it directly, but you can do it on this way:

```
int myIntBool = (someBoolean) ? 1 : 0;
```

Also, you can use [BooleanUtils from Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/BooleanUtils.html).

```
BooleanUtils.toInteger(true)  = 1
BooleanUtils.toInteger(false) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do `int x = b ? 1 : 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

ternary operation will yield the result

```
int y = booleanvalue ? 1: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Boolean To int**

```
int convertedInt=0;

if(booleanToConvert)
  convertedInt=1;
```

**Boolean to char**

```
char convertedChar='';

if(booleanToConvert)
  convertedChae='Y';
else
  convertedChae='N';
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly convert but manually like so:

```
int x = b ? 1 : 0; //sets x to 1 if b is true, 0 otherwise
```

The question now is why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

char c = Boolean.parseBoolean("true") ? '1' :  '0';
would set c to 1.
not quite sure if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**boolean to int:**

```
return booleanValue ? 1 : 0;
```

**boolean to char:**

```
return booleanValue ? 'Y' : 'N';
```

**boolean to String:**

```
return booleanValue ? "YES" : "NO";
```

And so on...