# Java: nice way to convert primitive boolean into primitive int (0,1)

Tags: java, type-conversion

I understand it should be pretty simple but...

- I have **primitive** java boolean.
- I believe such a simple things should not require additional method coding.
- I strongly dislike ternary operator and inline conditions (`?` for those who want reputation and trying to answer anything even without reading question). So `(value ? 1 : 0)` is not for me.
- I cannot use nice fragment like `value.compareTo(false)` because it is `primitive`.

What I'd like to get is something like last point but for primitives.
Surprised there is no good way to do such a plain useful conversion? Me to. Is your google bigger than my one? ;-D

**UPDATE:**

OK, finally I've decided to write my own method for this case as there is not only type conversion but some logic that could be extended in future and I'd like to have it encapsulated. Thanks to all people participated.

Comment: why you don't like ternary operator ?

Comment: There are many issues related to ternary. For me it is enough all my analysers dislike it and increase code complexity metrics too much.

Comment: @RomanNikitchenko no more so than an if statement, do you not use those as well?

Comment: which analyzer tool you are using ?

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3793669/1687499

Comment: What you want to do depends on the implementation of `Boolean.compareTo()` - the spec for `compareTo()` only requires that a positive or negative value is returned on greater-than or less-than comparisons. In the future this could in-theory return anything `> 0`

Comment: @Demplo Crazy... ;-D

Comment: `5 - Boolean(b).toString().length` (!)

Comment: @RomanNikitchenko Here's Oracle's implementation of `compare()` in JDK8 - `public static int compare(Boolean x, Boolean y) {return (x == y) ? 0 : (x ? 1 : -1); }` - Do your analyzers look into the platform source? o.O

Comment: @RomanNikitchenko yeah that's funny, so jealous it's not an idea of mine :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use `value.compareTo(false)` strictly because it's primitive, then how about

```
Boolean.valueOf(value).compareTo(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Comment: Although it's worth noting the Oracle JDK's implementation of this method uses a ternary operator.

Comment: Better than nothing boot looks too long. Isn't there shorten standard way?

Comment: Yes there is. It's `int i = value ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @Roman I should also point out that `compareTo` also uses a ternary operator in the Oracle implementation.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
boolean x = true;

System.out.println(Boolean.compare(x, false));
```

way number **2**:

```
System.out.println(5 - Boolean.toString(x).length());
```

way number **3** (longer):

```
boolean x = true;

try{
    System.out.println(Boolean.toString(x).charAt(4) - 101);
}catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    System.out.println(1);
}
```

Comment: You'll find that is implemented with two ternary operators: `return (x == y) ? 0 : (x ? 1 : -1);`

Answer (score 0):

There is no nice way.  An extra function definition isn't that bad.  Just define a function if you hate ternary:

```
int bool_to_int(boolean mybool) {
    if (mybool)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They mentioned not creating additional methods either.

Comment: __There is no other way, other than using ternary.__  At least this looks cleaner.

Comment: Sure there is, the ternary operator; which does exactly this without a method call.

Comment: *That's what I said.*  But if he hates ternary, this looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ternary operator is the most simple, most efficient, and most readable way to do what you want. I encourage you to use this solution.

However, I can't resist to propose an alternative, contrived, inefficient, unreadable solution.

```
int boolToInt(Boolean b) {
    return b.compareTo(false);
}
```

Comment: This depends on the implementation of `Boolean.compareTo()` - the spec for `compareTo()` only requires that a positive or negative value is returned on greater-than or less-than comparisons. In the future this could in-theory return anything `> 0`

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally this is best thing I've found:

```
public class Main {

    public static int resultCode(final boolean flag) {
        return Boolean.compare(flag, false);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        boolean v1 = false;
        boolean v2 = true;
        System.out.println(v1 + " > " + resultCode(v1));
        System.out.println(v2 + " > " + resultCode(v2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ideas for your method - thay are all exciting because hey are far more complicated than `b ? 1: 0`.

```
int bi1(boolean b) {
    // The number of items in a set containing both false and the value
    Set<Boolean> s = new HashSet<Boolean>();
    s.add(b);
    s.add(false);
    return s.size() - 1;
}

int bi2(boolean b) {
    // Side-effect usage.
    int bi = 0;
    boolean x = (b && (bi = 1) == 0);
    return bi;
}

int bi3(boolean b) {
    // Using Compareto in a gratuitously obscure way.
    return (int) Math.signum(("" + b).compareTo(Boolean.FALSE.toString()));
}

int bi4(boolean b) {
    // A twiddle too far.
    return ((int) ("" + !b).charAt(0)) >> 1 & 1;
}

int bi5(boolean b) {
    // The old if heave
    if (b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

static final List<Boolean> ltf = Arrays.asList(false, true);

int bi6(boolean b) {
    // List twiddling.
    return ltf.indexOf(b);
}
```

How many more do you want?