# Change return method from boolean to int

Tags: java, android, boolean

Can i convert in some way this method from boolean to int? so when i will call the method instead return true or false i can return 1 or 0:

```
public boolean openMode() {

return Settings.System.getBoolean(contxt.getConentResolver(), Setting.System.START_METHOD, true); 

}
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to write a function that returns `int`.  What is your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793650/convert-boolean-to-int-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter form, using a "ternary operator":

```
public int openMode()
{
    boolean value = Settings.System.getBoolean(contxt.getConentResolver(), Setting.System.START_METHOD, true);
    return (value == true ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: It's called "ternary operator"

Answer (score 3):

```
public int openMode(){
    boolean value = Settings.System.getBoolean(contxt.getConentResolver(), Setting.System.START_METHOD, true);

    if(value){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other programming languages like C, java does not recognizes 1 or 0 as true or false ( or boolean in short). So the return type of this method has to be boolean it self, you can not return 1 or 0 unless you change the method's return type. However, if you can change the method signature , you can change the return type to int and return 1 for true and 0 for false. example :

```
public int openMode(){
 return (Settings.System.getBoolean(contxt.getConentResolver(), Setting.System.START_METHOD, true))?1:0 ;
}
```