# Automatic promotion of boolean to int

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I read in a book Java supports automatic promotion and when I assigned a Boolean value to int it gives error
Now my question is since Boolean is one bit and int is 4 byte, it should get promoted but then why does it give me an error ?

Comment: A boolean is not a numeric value - it is true or false (not 1 or 0).

Comment: You have to code it. [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793650/convert-boolean-to-int-in-java)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793650/convert-boolean-to-int-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean is not a numeric type. Promotion only applies to compatible types.

Comment: How come Boolean is not a numeric type ? It stores either 1 or 0 so it should be a numeric type

Comment: Actually it stores either `true` or `false`. Nowhere in the standard it says that it's `0` or `1`. [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.5). An integer can be converted to a boolean value, but not the other way.