# Better pixel calculation method due to performance reasons

Tags: java, javafx

I have a method which takes a `javafx.scene.paint.color` as a parameter and returns either `black` or `white` as a `color` depending on the `brightness` of the given `color`.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public Color getPixelColor(Color color) {
    return color.getBrightness() > cutOff ? Color.WHITE : Color.BLACK;
}
```

Because this has to be done for each `pixel` of an `image` this method can take a while depending of the `image size`. (For an Full HD Image the code will run through 2 million `if` statements)

So my question is, if there is a way/calcuation, which gives you `0`(black) or `1`(white) as result but doesn't use any `if` statements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: aaaaaaaa but you didn specify javafx. in your prologue?? did you now?

Comment: Processing a fullhd image on the cpu willbe slow whatever you do. Especially in java. I'd look for some gpu accelerated solution. In this case I am pretty sure that not the ternary operator is the bottleneck.

Comment: @TamasHegedus, yes I am aware of that, but I wonder in general if it's possible to put such an if statement in a proper calculation

Comment: Since `java.awt.Color` doesn't have a `getBrightness()` method I'm going to assume you extended `Color` and added that method (you should have told us).  In that case, I suspect the bottleneck is in your `getBrightness()` method and not the cutoff calculation.

Comment: It is possible, you just did.

Comment: @JimGarrison he is using javafx.scene.paint.color

Comment: Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793650/convert-boolean-to-int-in-java) Id say this is the right way. If there was a builtin for that, that wouldnt be much faster anyway.

Comment: Ah... still I suspect the bottleneck is `getBrightness()`. Without actual profiling data optimizing the cutoff calculation is a stab in the dark.  It will be MUCH more expensive to calculate a relative brightness (several multiplies and/or divisions) compared to a simple threshold test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it was said in comments - I doubt that this particular function is bottleneck. But still you can optimize it.

If you go deeper and de-compile getBrightness function, you will see that it is actually converts R,G,B values to HSB and then returns only B. It uses com.sun.javafx.util.Utils.RGBtoHSB function for that

By going further, in [com.sun.javafx.util.Utils.RGBtoHSB](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/javafx/Utils.java#Utils.RGBtoHSB%28double%2Cdouble%2Cdouble%29) we will see that to calculate brightness, you need to pick maximal value from R,G,B

```
double cmax = (r > g) ? r : g;
if (b > cmax) cmax = b;
brightness = cmax;
```

so, we can either re-use this knowledge, like that (no array allocation, useless calculations of hue/saturation):

```
if ((clr.getRed() > cutoff) || (clr.getGreen() > cutoff) || (clr.getBlue() > cutoff)) {
    return Color.WHITE;
} else {
    return Color.BLACK;
}
```

or optimize it further (to eliminate if statements):

```
private static final Color[] BW_VALUES = {Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE};

public static Color convertToBW_1(final Color clr, final double cutoff) {
    /**
     * rd will be 0, if red channel under cutoff, ie black. rd will be 1, if red channel is above cutoff, ie white
     */
    final byte rd = (byte) (Double.doubleToRawLongBits(cutoff - clr.getRed()) >>> 63);
    final byte gd = (byte) (Double.doubleToRawLongBits(cutoff - clr.getGreen()) >>> 63);
    final byte bd = (byte) (Double.doubleToRawLongBits(cutoff - clr.getBlue()) >>> 63);

    /**
     * if at least one value is 1, then return white.
     */
    return BW_VALUES[rd | gd | bd];
}
```

According to my quick measurements - this variant 2 times faster, but your mileage may vary

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer