# Can you add a boolean return value to a local integer variable in java

Tags: java, boolean

I am relatively new to Java programming and I have a question regarding the following code. This is part of a class called IntArrayBag: the variable data is an array instance  and the variable manyItems is the instance used to hold the number of items of the array. In the removeMany method, I do not understand why you are able to increment count by adding the remove(target) method. Since remove returns a boolean, is count incremented every time the remove method evaluates to true? This could very well be the case, but I cannot find any documentation on it in my textbook. Any clarification would be very appreciated.

**EDIT The removeMany method listed below is an answer provided by my textbook. The question was to create a method that can remove multiple items from the array, and removeMany is the answer provided by the textbook. It did not seem logical to me, which is why I am asking for clarification. Thanks in advance.

```
public boolean remove(int target)
{ 
    int index;
    index = 0; 
    while ((index < manyItems) && (target != data[index])) 
        index++; 
        if (index == manyItems)
            return false; 
        else { 
            manyItems--; 
            data[index] = data[manyItems]; return true; } 
}

public int removeMany(int... targets) 
{ 
    int count = 0; 
    for (int target : targets) 
        count += remove(target); 
    return count; 
}
```

Comment: In correct java, you can't. And well, your partial input would not even compile. So; no idea what you are actually asking. So please provide a full [mcve]

Comment: The assignment you are confused with is indeed illegal. I consulted my `java` compiler (ver. 1.8.0_60) and it stated: `The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments by Izruo, the assignment is illegal. I believe the logic was to increment count every time a `remove` was successful. However, the boolean returned by the `remove` method must be changed to an `int` first so that you can increment `count` with it. You may look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793650/convert-boolean-to-int-in-java) post for doing that.

For example, this should work:

```
    public int removeMany(int... targets) 
{ 
    int count = 0; 
    for (int target : targets){
        int removeResult = (remove(target)) ? 1:
        count += removeResult; 
    }
return count; 
}
```