# efficient constant time conversion of boolean to int in java

Tags: java, cryptography

Constant time & work evaluations of expressions are important to prevent side-channel attacks in cryptographic algorithms.  However, I am not aware of any constant-time conversions between false/true and 0/1 in Java.

As a counter-example,

```
int x = p ? 1 : 0;
```

does not appear to have that property, since the branch in execution could mean there is a detectable difference in the evaluation of the expression.  In C/C++,

```
int x = p;
```

would do the trick, but this implicit conversion is not allowed in Java.  Is there a portable solution to this?  Faster of course is better.

Note this is not the same as [Convert boolean to int in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793650/convert-boolean-to-int-in-java)
because that question does not consider constant time.

Comment: (feel free to reopen/reclose)

Comment: Since Java may be interpreted, or may be compiled to machine code, using whatever algorithm the JVM wants, predicting exact performance of `p ? 1 : 0` is impossible. The JIT compiler may or may not actually eliminate the branch,

Comment: My point exactly.

Comment: Reopened and voted up. Gold for Java & Crypto :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, don't vote for this answer yet as I don't have time to verify it, but I was thinking about:

```
public static int toIntConstantTime(final boolean b) {
    int x = 0;
    x |= b ? 0b01 : 0b10;
    x |= !b ? 0b10 : 0b01;
    return (x & ~(x >> 1)) & 0b01;
}
```

which makes the answer always perform the operation, performs the branch both ways and relies on both bits.

Comment: I'll try and verify tomorrow (maybe Warren wants to give it a spin before that)...

Comment: Cool.  Since there are different execution paths, the timing could still be different (code cache miss or the like).  It would be nice if there is some answer that does not have differing paths.  I'm starting to think that is impossible...

Comment: I actually ran into same problem. Your answer assumes being that the time differences due to branching in 2nd line will be offset by the one in the third making net timing difference 0. I still cannot rely on it as it may even be different in different JVM's and machines.